# Spring Boot Project cannot run by IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Edit:
Here's the WebApplication file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I am using IntelliJ(15.0.2) to run a spring boot project,

It is working properly when I execute `java -jar spring-boot-sample.war`
Unfortunately it failed to run by IDE and complained **Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean**

The error details are as follows:

```
[2016-07-25 12:32:46.979] boot - 5719 ERROR [restartedMain] --- SpringApplication: Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.rentacoder.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 13 more
[2016-07-25 12:32:47.014] boot - 5719  INFO [restartedMain] --- ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener: Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/hzhang/work/workplace/IdeaProjects/RHS/target/classes/]
```

Below is the dependencies settings in the POM file:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Did I miss something in POM settings?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run it using a _spring boot application class_. Can you share that as well? Also can you try uncommenting the `<scope>provided</scope> from the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` so when you launch the application it will use the embedded tomcat and retry?

Comment: @Morfic  Please check my edit, I post the application file; I commented out <scope>provided</scope> from the spring-boot-starter-tomcat, unfortunately, it is still not working

Comment: USe  @SpringBootApplication annotation before class defination

Comment: Is that all of it? Like @PankajKumar suggested, how are you configuring your spring context, java-annotation or XML?

Comment: Everything seems fine ....just try adding that annotation..as your spring is not starting...this annotation helps to boot

Comment: @PankajKumar please see my edit. I have annotations. I suspect my configuration is wrong. I only configured `Main class` and `Use classpath of module`

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, you can add a jar configuration that uses the resulting jar from target folder.

In this way you can start the application normally or in debug mode.

As a drawback for this approach: you won't have the hotswap available and you will see the changes only after a maven build. But in this case I usually add in the add jar run configuration window in before section a maven goal with "clean package -DskipTests" so each time I press run I will have the latest changes available.

This is a quickfix; the problem can be solved in other ways - I done it some times ago but I can't remember exactly what was the problematic dependency - you need to dig a little in Spring source code with some debugging around the methods from which the exception jumps.

Answer (score -1):

How did you set the Configuration on IntelliJ? Since it's a WAR file, you'd need to have a web server container. Your pom has spring-boot-starter-tomcat, so you'll need to create a Tomcat Server configuration. This is a paid feature in IntelliJ, so you probably can't do it with the community edition.

A work-around is to create a Remote Debugging on your war file:
http://blog.trifork.com/2014/07/14/how-to-remotely-debug-application-running-on-tomcat-from-within-intellij-idea/

Comment: @RickChen  Can you please provide some valid link? The one you posted is empty.  BTW, I am using Intellij Ultimate

Comment: Not trying to be patronising, but do you have any official docs to support your statement that `you'll need a tomcat server configuration in IJ after adding spring-boot-starter-tomcat`? As far as I know it's the exact opposite, it will provide you with an [embedded tomcat preconfigured to make it _work out of the box_](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), so you can run your app from the _main class_. After all, I believe this is the reasoning behind boot being opinionated, am I wrong?

Comment: @HaifengZhang the link works if you remove the `]` at the end, it's most likely an unfortunate formatting error

Comment: @Morfic Thanks for correcting the link. I've updated the answer. As for the question of embedded vs running in a container, you were right that boot can do both. Since the OP didn't specify the entire pom file for me to see the packaging tag, I made an assumption based on the fact that it had produced a war instead of a jar, which would create the Embed error that he experienced.